# Datastore model design with ancestors

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, data-modeling

I've used Datastore for two projects now, but for both projects I failed to utilize the ancestor relationships. After a lot of reading and researching, I believe I've finally understood how to design a great Datastore model.

Imagine a site similar to Reddit/Instagram, where users can create their own Categories (similar to Subreddits) that other users can subscribe to. Users can follow each other, and images uploaded by different users will be uploaded to these Categories, as well as displayed under the specific user's profile (like in Instagram). With that in mind, this is what I figured would be the ideal design:

```
Category
- User
- - Image
- Subscriber
User
- Follower
- Following
```

With this Datastore model, I believe it should be possible to easily retrieve all images uploaded by 'user id' or 'category id',  all users subscribing to 'category id', all images uploaded to 'category id'. All users following or being followed by 'user id', all images uploaded by users being followed by 'user id'.

I would greatly appreciate feedback and potential ways to improve it by some Datastore expert (I'm particuarly curious about if there's anything wrong with using the 'User' as ancestor in two different locations, for which it's a child to 'Category' in one place but not the other)..

---

I hope this will help make the question more understandable/answerable :)

I have the following entities:

```
Category
- ID int64
- Name string
- etc..

User
- Username string (NameKey)
- Password []byte
- etc..

Image
- ID int64
- StorageID string
- MD5Hash string
- etc..

Follow
- ID int64
- Follower string
- Following string
```

Where Category, User, Image and Follow are the entities and ID, Name, Username, etc. are the property names.

So the Image entity would be descended from User (who uploaded the image) and Category ancestors

The Follow entity would be descended from User ancestor

As for Subscriber I'm not sure if it's best to make an entirely new Entity similar to Follow (in which case it could potentially include the Date the user first subscribed), or let it become a property

Comment: What language is this exactly?

Comment: @Y2H I'm using Golang, but I believe designing a proper [Datastore model with ancestors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/queries) is the same no matter what language is used (I mean the ancestor relationship should be the same)

Comment: Yes it should be. Unfortunately as I am not familiar with Go I am unable to understand your model so I can’t help you. Sorry for not being helpful.

Comment: I think it's more about how easy to understand/answer the question is. This one is pretty open ended, which makes it harder to reply in the Q&A format. As an example, it's not clear which are entities and which are properties.

Comment: @DanMcGrath you're right, I can see the question kinda had a completely different view after I updated it to specify the entities :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity groups (all entities with the same root ancestor, including the root ancestor) are more about consistency units when querying. One issue with this design will be scaling since entity groups are limited to a sustained 1 transaction per second (you can burst higher).

With this current design all you queries within a single category will be strongly consistent, but you'd be limited to 1 new image per second.

Since it's likely that having a strongly consistent view of all images in a category isn't as important as ensuring you can handle growth, it might be better to have images descend from the root user entity (so a user looking for their own images is strongly consistent) and have category just an id in a property of the image entity.

```
Category
- ID int64
- Name string
- OwnerUserID string
- etc..

User
- Username string (NameKey)
- Password []byte
- etc..

Image (descends from User)
- ID int64
- StorageID string
- MD5Hash string
- CategoryID int64
- etc..
```

Now to list all images for a user 123 (strongly consistent):

```
SELECT * FROM Image WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR (User, 123)
```

List all images for a user 123 in category 456 (strongly consistent):

```
SELECT * FROM Image WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR (User, 123) AND CategoryID = 456
```

List all images in a category 456 (eventually consistent):

```
SELECT * FROM Image WHERE CategoryID = 456
```

List all images (eventually consistent)

```
SELECT * FROM Image
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. If I understand correctly, the reason Category should not be an ancestor of Image is not because it's a 'nested' ancestor relationship (it's perfectly fine to have nested ancestors, right?), but because different users will likely upload images to Category (for which 1 write per second will be a problem.. similar to how different Reddit users will post submissions to a given subreddit), but for a given user it's not a problem if can only upload 1 image per second (I also believe that in this case it should be possible to use multiput to upload a batch of images together)

Comment: Similarly, the Follow entity can have User as root ancestor because a given User won't follow more than one per second (like Twitter/Instagram) unless they automate it (and in this case it should also be no big deal if there's a delay to write the Follow operations)

Comment: You got it, both comments (Inc multiput) are correct.